# Can't find element belonging to 'Accept All' button

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I recently started learning Selenium and webscraping in Python. I'm trying to find and click the 'Accept All' button on the pop-up (image of the pop-up can be found below) when entering the following site: https://www.sherdog.com, using Chrome. It takes around 5 seconds for the pop-up to load. I have tried different things and have red what I could find on stackoverflow describing similar problems. To no avail. I always get the NoSuchElementException (or NoAlertPresentException).

[image]

I have tried the following things:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get('https://www.sherdog.com')
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'Button__StyledButton-a1qza5-0 incZp')
driver.switch_to.alert
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'Button__StyledButton-a1qza5-0 incZp')))
except:
    print("An exception occurred")
```

I also thought I might have to switch frame using `driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("rufous-sandbox")))`, but am honestly unsure which frame to select. When looking through the HTML code (which I just started learning) I see some references to JavaScript (of which I have zero knowledge). Maybe that is causing me trouble?

If anybody could provide some insight, or point me in the right direction, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which Accept All button, is it for cookies? Can you share the screenshot highlighting the element you want to take action on.

Comment: @ketanvj I added a screenshot of the pop-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you click that element:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
actions = ActionChains(browser)

url = 'https://www.sherdog.com'
browser.get(url) 
elem = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@title='Scroll to the bottom of the text below to enable this button']")))

elem.click()
print('clicked')
```

Bear in mind that, if window is not sufficiently large, that text will need to be scrolled (and button will not be clickable). Default headless window size is quite small, so make sure your window is sufficiently large.
Selenium docs: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

Comment: Yes, it worked like a charm! Now I need to go under the hood and figure out how you did it :-). Especially how to use the XPATH still seems a bit mysterious to me. But now I have enough things to delve into. I have red (most of) the documentation on the selenium site, but found that it doesn't explain everything. But, thanks a lot! Helped a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

1. There are 2 objects you need to close there and they are not alerts. So `driver.switch_to.alert` is not relevant here.
2. Always try using stable unique locators. Class names like `incZp` may often be dynamic and not reliable.
3. `Button__StyledButton-a1qza5-0 incZp` are actually 2 class names, so you have to use CSS_SELECTOR or XPATH to work with them.
4. It is always preferred to wait for element visibility, not just existence when you going to click on that element.

This should work:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get('https://www.sherdog.com')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Continue')]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#cookieNotice a.cnaccept"))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the explanation! Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work this way. I tried to replace wait with WebDriverWait, but then I got a TypeError: until() missing 1 required positional argument: 'method'.

Comment: Sorry, updated with creation of `wait` object. Also, in case you see only 1 pop-up remove the first line `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Continue')]"))).click()
`

Comment: I only get 1 pop-up, so ignored the first line. But when I run the second line `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#cookieNotice a.cnaccept"))).click()` I get an ElementClickInterceptedException.

Comment: Well, I see you already accepted some answer here, so looks like it resolved your problems

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element <kbd>Accept Cookies</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.sherdog.com")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div>a.cnaccept"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.sherdog.com")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='cnaccept']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to clarify which 'Accept All' button it concerned (I added a screenshot). But this is also useful for me to see. Thanks a bunch!